# How to convert the time column in int type to 23:53:20.081?

Tags: dolphindb

How to convert the time column in int type to 23:53:20.081?

Now, I set the time column in int type such as: a = 95200820 which means the time 09:25:00.820, b = 192500820 which means time 19:25:00.820. In dolphindb, how to convert the int type to a correct time type?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use the “string()” function to convert the type from int to string, and then use the “lpad()” function to fill in the specified characters on the left, then use the “temporalParse” function to convert it to the time type in dolphindb.
Specific examples are as follows:

```py
b = 92500820
datetimeParse(lpad(string(b), 9, "0"), "HHmmssSSS")
```

And the result is:

```py
09:25:00.820
```